# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) in browser when making xml request using axios

Tags: javascript, xml, axios

I am trying to send xml request to web service and receive xml response.

Below is my code:

```
handleClick(MessageId) {

        console.log(MessageId);

        // this.setState({loading: true});        
          var serviceURL = 'http://192.168.2.13:8080/Service/com/xmlService';
          let xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><msgIdList><Id>'+MessageId+'</Id></msgIdList>';  
          console.log(xmlString);      

          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: serviceURL,
            data: xmlString,
            config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' }}
            })
            .then(response => {
                //handle success                            
                console.log(response);

            })
            .catch( response => {
                //handle error
                console.log(response);              
          }); 


      }
```

But it gives error below :

```
415 (Unsupported Media Type) in browser.
```

Same is working using postman.

What wrong I am doing..?

Comment: You need to compare the raw requests. Go into the network tab, and compare all the request headers and bodies with each other, and check for differences. If it's working in postman, modify your axios to mimic each header that you may think is causing it, one at a time, until you figure out which piece is causing your issue.

Comment: Does axios support xml request as they haven't provided docs..?